# React Native: Native module AppStateModule tried to override AppStateModule for module name AppState

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a working iOS react native app ( react native v 0.38 ). I tried to run the same app in android as well.
[image]
I've manually linked all this libraries (which i'm using in iOS now) :

```
react-native-camera
react-native-code-push
react-native-device-info
react-native-google-analytics-bridge
react-native-i18n
react-native-push-notification
react-native-restart
react-native-sqlite-storage
```

Settings.gradle :

```js
include ':app'
include ':react-native-sqlite-storage'
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android')
include ':react-native-restart'
project(':react-native-restart').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-restart/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':app', ':react-native-i18n'
project(':react-native-i18n').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-i18n/android')
include ':react-native-google-analytics-bridge', ':app'
project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,   '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
```

build.gradle :

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Android/app/build.gradle :

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.opencampus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    compile project(':react-native-restart')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

AndroidManifest :

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.opencampus"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainApplication.java :

```js
package com.opencampus;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.avishayil.rnrestart.ReactNativeRestartPackage;
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;
import com.idehub.GoogleAnalyticsBridge.GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera.RCTCameraPackage;
import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    // 2. Override the getJSBundleFile method in order to let
    // the CodePush runtime determine where to get the JS
    // bundle location from on each app start
    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new SQLitePluginPackage(),
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
          new ReactNativeI18n(),
          new GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo(),
          new CodePush("-", MainApplication.this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
          new RCTCameraPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Any Solutions please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the issue. In MainApplication.java , new MainReactPackage(), was included two times.

```
package com.opencampus;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.avishayil.rnrestart.ReactNativeRestartPackage;
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;
import com.idehub.GoogleAnalyticsBridge.GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera.RCTCameraPackage;
import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    // 2. Override the getJSBundleFile method in order to let
    // the CodePush runtime determine where to get the JS
    // bundle location from on each app start
    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new SQLitePluginPackage(),
          new MainReactPackage(), **<<<<< **** included two times**
          new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
          new ReactNativeI18n(),
          new GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo(),
          new CodePush("-", MainApplication.this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
          new RCTCameraPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add it by yourself or what? :D

Comment: @HenrikR what do you mean? Yeah it was a mistake by myself

Comment: Exactly my problem too. Thanks for the fix! I think `react-native link ...` can duplicate packages sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

remove package from protected `List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {}`, auto-linking already added packages

Comment: this fixed my issue with watermelonDB